# How can I calculate probability from the log-normal distribution probability density function graph in python?

Tags: python, probability-density, probability-distribution

How can I find probability between certain values from the lognormal distribution probability density function with Python?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using Scipy to calculate these kind of probability functions.
Example of what you asked:

```
import scipy.stats as stats

print(stats.lognorm(1.).cdf(.7)-stats.lognorm(1.).cdf(.5))
```

Here is the link with documentation about a.o. the parameters.
[http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/~francois.denis/IAAM1/scipy-html-1.0.0/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html](http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/%7Efrancois.denis/IAAM1/scipy-html-1.0.0/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html)

Comment: Thank you so much and can I ask something too, this code is works and for example I wonder of probabiliy on the probability denstiy function between 150-200 values, so this code is how should be? I'm new on this subject, I'm sorry if I asked the wrong thing please

Comment: You would have to calculate stats.lognorm(1.).cdf(200)-stats.lognorm(1.).cdf(150).
But this is for the lognormal distribution with sigma=1 and mu=0, if you want the result for a lognormal distribution with other parameters, you will have to change the (1.) and do some translation.